# Steady-state density and change of variables

Tags: stochastic-calculus, density-function, stochastic-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Consider the $n$-dimensional stochastic differential equation
$$
\mathrm{d}X_t = f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t +\mathrm{d}W_t,
$$
where $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is some smooth function and $W_t$ is a Wiener process.

If the vector field $f(X)$ is a gradient flow, that is, if it can be written as $f(X)=-\nabla U(X)$ for some potential function $U\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, it is well-known that $x$ has a steady-state density (i.e. the stationary solution to the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)) which is given by (up to normalizing constants)
$$
p_{ss}(X) = \exp(-U(X)),
$$

Consider now a vector field $f$ of the form:
$$
f(X)=-\nabla U(Y)|_{Y=g(X)}\ \ \ \ \ (\ast)
$$
where $g\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is some smooth function. In this case $f(X)$ is still a gradient flow, but with respect to the variable $Y=g(X)$.

**My question** : What it can be said about the steady-state density $p_{ss}(X)$ when  $(\ast)$ holds?

My approach would be that of considering an extended state space in which the drift can be written as a gradient flow, and then marginalizing the resulting steady-state density. Does it make sense? Is there any more clever/easier approach?

Any comment is welcome, as well as pointers to literature. Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what the effect of generic smooth function $g$ is. The work "An SDE perspective on stochastic convex optimization" is quite generic and they still need some convexity assumptions.

Comment: My guess is that some lemmas from that paper will go through and they will guide you on the constraints that need to be imposed on $g$. For example, their Descent Lemma 2.1, might require you to have $g$ be globally Lipschitz.